# C#. Многопоточный счетчик

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Необходим простенький класс-счетчик, который будет возвращать число и увеличивать на 1. Вот такой класс есть сейчас:

```
class Sequence
{
    private ulong _number { get; set; }
    public Sequence()
    {
        this._number = ((UInt64)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public ulong Next()
    {
        return _number++;
    }
}
```

Доступ к нему имеют несколько потоков, и практически без задержек получают новое число функцией `Next()`. Иногда вылетала вот такая ошибка `InvalidOperationException: out of sync`, и бывали моменты когда в нескольких потоках было одинаковое число. Как можно сделать синхронизацию, при этом не в ущерб производительности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не должны экономить на спичках и жалеть одну несчастную блокировку. Но если очень хочется:

```
class Sequence
{
    private long number;

    public Sequence()
    {
        long startValue = ...; // вычисляйте как угодно
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref number, startValue);
    }

    public ulong Next()
    {
        return (ulong)Interlocked.Increment(ref number);
    }
}
```

---

Обратите внимание, что `InvalidOperationException` не могло быть выброшено при простом увеличении переменной, даже пускай несинхронизированном. Ищите эту ошибку ещё где-то.

Comment: Только компилятор ругается на то что переменную класса нельзя передавать как `ref`

Comment: @DimaGvozdev: Странно, сейчас уточню.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev: Вы случайно не сделали `number` свойством?

Comment: А, да. Не убрал { get; set; }